# What are the Map Sessions limitations for the free plan offered by Skobbler (Telenav)?

Tags: skmaps

I plan to use Skobbler maps iOS SDK for one of my project, but before using it inside my project I need to know the Map Sessions limitations for the free plan. In that sense I browsed the company's website and I found two different answers to my question:

1 - The first one that I found is located in the plans' description:

[image]

([Source of this screenshot](http://developer.skobbler.com/#plans))

First 1 Million FREE.

2 - The second one that I found is located in the terms of api's usage.

[image]

([Source of this screenshot](http://www.skobbler.com/legal#termsSDK))

50,000 monthly map views.

Billable Event >250,000 map sessions (including online routing): $0.50/1,000 additional map sessions.

50,000 monthly map views and you apparently start charging when we do a number of requests >250,000 map sessions.

**I do not know if all these information are not up-to-date, but for the moment they really confuse me and it would be really cool if Skobbler (Telenav) or someone on this forum could provide us some clarifications about the pricing applied to an iOS developer using the Skobbler FREE plan?**

Comment: "it would be really cool if Skobbler (Telenav) or someone on this forum could provide us some clarification"  Have you considered asking them?

Comment: Yes, actually this is what I did in this post and right below one product manager of Skobbler has just answered to my question, fantastic isn't it? Which is more outstanding is that on the support page of Skobbler website, they ask to the users of the API to ask their questions on StackOverflow, using skmaps tag. So I am really sorry if I have bothered you asking that question, but I would have been really glad to find a clarification on that point on StackOverflow, unfortunately I have not been able to find that information, so I asked on SO which is the goal of this forum just as a reminder.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the 2.4 update, due to an error, the T&C was reverted to the, pre-October 2014 version.

It will be fixed right away - the T&C will properly reflect what is on the plans page:

- the first 1 million map sessions are free
- the first 10k small & large maps are free
- 0.50$ per 1000 map sessions
- 0.02$ for a small offline map
- 0.08$ for a large offline map